# Is there a way to change some value when my app is running in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background

I'm working in a location based app that allows the user to share his location with some other users for certain periods of time (15 minutes, 30 minutes, 60 minutes, 1 day), the thing is when the time, setted by the user, has finished I need to change his status to false, send a HTTP post with the status and stop sharing his location, even if the app is running in background. I have tried using the new Background Tasks API provided by Apple in iOS 13 but I found reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/starting_and_terminating_tasks_during_development?language=objc) that it can take many hours and I need to do it when the time stablished finish. Is there a way to accomplish the job inside the application or should I use server side operations to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the “significant change” location service or “region monitoring” (aka, “geofencing”). These work even if your app is in the background, but isn’t as battery crushing as the standard location services.

See [Handling location updates in the background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/handling_location_updates_in_the_background/) or [Monitoring the user's proximity to geographic regions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/monitoring_the_user_s_proximity_to_geographic_regions).